# MySql: Error #1242 updating a column with data taken from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to update a column of a table, currently empty, with the data taken from another table.

I have two tables. The "ar_geozone" table has the following structure

```
ID -> primary key;
code_countries;
code_city;
name_city;
longitude_city;
latitude_city;
name_countries;
name_regions;
kind_regions.
```

The "name_regions, kind_regions" columns are empty and I would like to update only the "name_regions" column

The second "regions" table has the following structure:

```
country;
code;
name;
kind.
```

All the columns in the table "regions" have records. However, the number of records is lower than those in the table "ar_geozone".

Using the following query

```
UPDATE ar_geozone ct 
    SET name_regions = 
     (SELECT name FROM regions ag 
      WHERE ag.country LIKE ct.code_countries)
```

the system gives me the error:

> "#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row".

How should I modify the query to update the column?

Comment: You need to find a way such that the subquery only returns one row.  Some sample data would be helpful here.

Comment: is the table empty? or just that 1 field is empty?

Comment: Apparently there are more than one records in table `regions` matching the to-be-updated record in table `ar_geozone`. You need to somehow specify which one should be used for the `UPDATE`.

Comment: do you have a common primary key field in both the tables?

Comment: Does 'country' column of 'regions' table is unique

Comment: It's not just a matter of MySQL being picky about the syntax. What logical result do you expect whenever you get more than one name? You can't store several values in a single cell!

Comment: The sql string should update the "ar_geozone.name_regions" column, with the data in the "regions.name" column, when it finds a match between "regions.country" and "ar_geozone.code_countries"

Comment: Yeah, that part is kind of clear. Now, let's imagine you have `UK` as country and `England`, `Wales`, `Scotland` and `Northern Ireland` as regions. What exactly do you want the update to produce? How many rows are there in `ar_geozone` for `UK`? One, four or none of the above? Can you describe it with words? You should really edit the question and post examples of the data both tables have and what it should look like afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

SQL LIKE Operator fetches more than one row. Which means you are trying to update name_regions with more than one country names.

```
UPDATE ar_geozone ct 
    SET name_regions = 
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ', ') FROM regions ag 
      WHERE ag.country LIKE ct.code_countries)
```

It will combine more than one row into comma separated String.